# Which Ruby implementation is the most widely used? (MRI, Rubinius, JRuby etc.)

Tags: ruby

As a novice to Ruby, I am a little bit confused as to which Ruby implementation is the most widely used in the industry.

I personally like to stay on the edge and therefore use MRI, but I get that a lot of people do not like it because of the GIL and prefer to use Rubinius instead, (which is pretty close to MRI), however I also gather that a lot of folks use JRuby (for Swing and such), however JRuby seems to be pretty far behind as far as Ruby development goes, (somewhere on the 1.9 line?).

Which implementation is the most commonly used in the industry?

Comment: All of them... Learn all... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most straight forward projects, which don't require multi-threading, need to integrate with specific libraries, or run on certain containers - most people would prefer using the `MRI` implementation.

The main reason is that most ruby libraries are developed for `MRI`, and tested on them. You might have certain compatibility problems on other implementations.

Rubinius is preferred if you plan to work on a multi-threaded architecture, like under [`puma`](http://puma.io/). `JRuby` also has better support for threads, and also has the rich library portfolio of the Java community. It is also preferred if you want to run on a java-based runtime container.